# How can I specify which layout to use for an Android Wearable?

Tags: android, android-layout, wear-os

I have a custom view with an onTouch method that launches another activity with its own xml layout.  If I run the program on an emulator that has been scaled to watch size (yes only scaled, normal emulator is fine), it creates an instance of the new activity with both the round and rect layout files.  Additionally logcat says eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented.

Because this only happens on scaled emulator, is it just a bug with the emulator? I don't have a real android wear watch yet.  Or is there a way to package some attribute with the intent that starts the activity to let it know I want one of the layouts?

Edit: It's having this problem on the emulator regardless of size/shape

Comment: Why is the normal emulator fine?  The watches actually run a trimmed down version of Android called 4.4W.  If you test against the normal emulator and not the one targets at the watches you may run into issues when you try to run on an actual device.

Answer (score 3):

The best way to target specific screen sizes or aspect ratios is by using [qualifiers for alternate resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources).

Based on the developer documentation, using the `watch` qualifier for your resource will probably do the trick.  Your directory hierarchy would look something like this:

```
src/
res/
    layout/
        (all of your regular layouts)
    layout-watch/
        (all of your Android Wearable layouts)
```

Comment: The project wizard automatically separates all wear components into one module, and mobile into another.  Right now I don't have any mobile layouts, besides the default hello world.  Also the main layout for the activity has attributes referencing both the rect and round layouts, and until now, has handled choosing between them automatically